# How do separate single message filed into multiple fields for the logs ingested from filebeat to elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

Logs are transmitted as below

ECS --> Filebeat --> Elastic

I am getting the logs in Kibana(Elastic), but the problem is I get a message field. I need the message field to decode into multiple fileds

Below is the message field.
{"name":"automation","level":"INFO","action":"apiCall","app":"Node","env":"dev","input_type":"log","type":"json","apiCall":{"request":{"method":"POST","uri":"http://internal-orderhive-development-1865807702.ap-southeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com/orders/custom/event%22,%22body%22:%22{"sync_created_from":"2023-03-07 02:58:00","sync_created_to":"2023-03-07 06:58:00","source":{"event":"customOrderEvent","event_id":131}

But i need "name", "level" , "apiCall" as different fields so i can filter out the logs easily from kibana.

I have attached the filebeat.yml file as well.

[fileebat.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CECbh.png)

Comment: filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
      - /var/tmp/OrderhiveNode.log

processors:
 - decode_json_fields:
   fields: ["message"]
   target: ""
   overwrite_keys: true
processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~
output.elasticsearch.allow_older_versions:  true
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["@#############################"]
  username: "log#$##############"
  password: "H#####################"
  protocol: "https"
  index: "devautomationlogs-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"          
  allow_older_versions: true

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use an [ingestion pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/ingest.html) with [json processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/json-processor.html) to process the file and split it into parts